# Apple Push Notification Service keys

Tags: asn.1, elliptic-curve

I have an EC key generated by Apple Push Notification Service (APN).
As per the [RFC5915 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915#section-3) the key should be a sequence [that looks like this one](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#30770201010420ABF564CCD9F14C6DFD8C7074AA4C00FD27955EE77BC821D3EE46FB919BFED314A00A06082A8648CE3D030107A14403420004BEE62C3FE427AEA01B33B2328738EDD3C8454AECDAA72A23081FE016C06DEB95A2AF84D8AF97D243DEA86B8A9E19579317397E7C68991482E8A2DBCBB223F001).

My problem is that the APN key sequence is encapsulated into another sequence that is not described in the RFC5915. [Here is the result I get](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#308193020100301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D030107047930770201010420D779F78AC7EC124B7397E0AD1F9102A51ACA93EE34A6B56E09B95D90FEFB81A9A00A06082A8648CE3D030107A1440342000461C20C5246A5C1B79E01591417A14FDDA055942CE5AB111DEE2D2E37FE2BA00D6D4F30396241913359EB5801D7FE31A7EAFCFAE56C401F03E97B25F9A28C0B2F).

Does anyone know where this sequence is described?

Comment: I have no idea, but I did notice that the intro to RFC5915 mentions putting ECPrivateKey in the PrivateKey field of a PrivateKeyInfo.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I think you are right; the first sequence is the PrivateKeyInfo described in the [RFC5208](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5208). As your comment was relly helpful, could you please write an answer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these RFC's or APN, I just know about ASN.1, and I only made a simple observation, so I'm not going to write an authoritative answer.  Glad it helped you, though.